# Schnorr signature key storage

Tags: wallet, private-key, schnorr-signatures

So everyone talks about Schnorr signatures and Taproot when talking about Bitcoin. I would like to know if there is any standard that they will use to store the keys used in this algorithm. And also I would like to know if there is any standard for storing the signature. Thanks :)

Comment: I don't know for Bitcoin specific, but note that how a private key is stored is generally left up to the application; as the private key is usually not transported anywhere, compatibility is usually not of much importance. Have you looked at any specific Bitcoin specifications already?

Comment: Up until know I read the BIP340 where is the algorithm is presented. I want to implement an application that will work with Schnorr signatures and I wanted to know if there is any standard for the public key storage because they did not specify anything. Same thing with the signature. They only specified the length of both signature and public key

Comment: There are several standards for *deriving* keys from seeds (including BIP 39 for seed phrases, BIP 32 for the key derivation algorithms and the concept of master keys, BIP 86 for standard derivation paths for taproot key based outputs, ...). Typically software will store private keys in one of these (seed phrases, master keys, or extended private keys), and public keys in whatever form they're used (possibly as addresses). Is this the kind of information you're looking for, or something else?

Comment: (Maybe this is not your question but) BIP340 actually specifies everything you're looking for. For example, public keys are byte arrays of length 32. So this is already a serialized format. Just store the 32 byte array. For details, see the pubkey generation algorithm: https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0340.mediawiki#public-key-generation It uses the *bytes()* helper function (also defined in the BIP), which takes care of the serialization. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I would like to know if there is any standard like let's say PEM for that or anything. I know it specifies that they are byte arrays of length 32. But is it safe to store only the byte array in a file let's say?